# How do I dynamically set attributes on the HTML element or add HEAD/(LINK|TITLE) elements in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-rtl

I have an Angular 12 application that I am trying to make work with both LTR and RTL languages (e.g. English and Arabic respectively) which can be chosen and applied by the end user when using the application. Bootstrap - which I use for UI style - requires that I set the dir attribute on the HTML element and that I reference a separate RTL CSS file from the original LTR CSS file when I want to display Arabic text.

I thought I would be able to set up my **index.html** like this:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

And then have my **app-component.html** generate the HTML, HEAD, LINK and BODY elements, etc. like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html [lang]="lang" [dir]="dir">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link *ngIf="dir != 'rtl'" href="/assets/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link *ngIf="dir == 'rtl'" href="/assets/styles/bootstrap.rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>

</html>
```

However, when I attempted this layout, the Bootstrap menus (and other JavaScript action related styles) stopped working. I noticed that now, when Chrome fetches **index.html**, Angular has inserted its bootstrapping scripts *ahead* of the `app-root` element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="styles.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
<app-root></app-root>
```

I also noticed from the DevTools Elements view that Chrome had nested my HTML element inside the `app-root` element of a document of its own creation.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="runtime.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="polyfills.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="styles.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="vendor.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="main.js" defer=""></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root _nghost-tyi-c80="" ng-version="12.0.5">
      <html _ngcontent-tyi-c80="" lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <head _ngcontent-tyi-c80="">
          <meta _ngcontent-tyi-c80="" charset="utf-8">
          ...
        </head>
        ...
      </html>
    </app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Snip of the Elements view in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8wY3.png)

If I revert my change, then Chrome fetches **index.html** and I see that Angular inserts its bootstrapping scripts *after* the `app-root` element and *before* the closing `body` tag. Bootstrap likes this and the menus start working again but I lose control over dynamically choosing which LTR or RTL CSS link gets emitted, and whether the HTML element has meaningful LANG and DIR attributes, and any other changes to HEAD elements like the page title.

**Original index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Snappy Title Goes Here</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="/assets/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

What Chrome sees:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Snappy Title Goes Here</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="/assets/styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="polyfills.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="styles.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="vendor.js" defer=""></script>
  <script src="main.js" defer=""></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What is the correct way to dynamically alter these HTML and HEAD-related attributes and elements so that Chrome doesn't get confused?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with leaving original `index.html` with one change, add tag `dir-change` to bootstrap stylesheet which will allow later to find it.

`<link href="/assets/styles/bootstrap.css" dir-change/>`

then in `app.component.ts` add method that will update this link and direction

```
 changeDirection(dir: 'ltr'| 'rtl'): void {
   const attrName = 'dir-change'
   const originalLink = document.querySelector(`[${attrName}]`);
   const linkAddress = dir === 'ltr' ?
    "/assets/styles/bootstrap.css"
    :"/assets/styles/bootstrap.rtl.css";
   (originalLink as HTMLLinkElement).href = linkAddress;
   document.dir = dir;
 }
```